# cannot find module when uploading to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

Im developing an app with react redux, when I run my backend app on localhost it works fine, but when I deploy it to heroku the `require`stop working. I get the following error `Cannot find module '../api/user/authService'`.

Im using nodejs 8.0.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post your app code.

Comment: We can't answer with so little information. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].